# chnage marquee direction on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

this is the code I have:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('image_runner').direction='left';">LEFT</a>
     - <a href="#" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('image_runner').direction='right';">RIGHT</a>
<marquee direction="left" style="width: 900px; margin: auto;" id="image_runner" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('image_runner').stop();" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('image_runner').start();">
<ul style="margin-top:0px;">
  <li>asda</li>
  <li class="right">asdsa</li>
  <li class="right">assda</li>
</ul>
</marquee>
```

for some reason, it's not changing the direction of the marquee.

any ideas?

Comment: This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Comment: `<marquee>` is deprecated, old, weird and abandoned. You must to use a plugin like jquery marquee to control and compatibilize all your functionality: https://plugins.jquery.com/marquee/

Answer (score 0):

Marquee cannot change direction while running. You have to stop it, change direction then start again, but it will start from the beggining.

```js
document.getElementById('left').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  var marquee = document.getElementById('image_runner');
  marquee.stop();
  marquee.direction = 'left';
  marquee.start();
});
document.getElementById('right').addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  var marquee = document.getElementById('image_runner');
  marquee.stop();
  marquee.direction = 'right';
  marquee.start();
});
```

```html
<marquee direction="left" style="width: 900px; margin: auto;" id="image_runner" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('image_runner').stop();" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('image_runner').start();">
  <ul style="margin-top:0px;">
    <li>asda</li>
    <li class="right">asdsa</li>
    <li class="right">assda</li>
  </ul>
</marquee>
<a href="#" id="left">LEFT</a>
- <a href="#" id="right">RIGHT</a>
```